# Course Builder 1.5.1 'ImportError: No module named html5lib'

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I just upgraded my coursebuilder course to Course builder version 1.5.1. I ran into an issue where html5lib isn't working. Has anyone dealt with this or know how to get around it? I noticed that when I downloaded the course-builder demo application, it also suffers the same problem. Below is the stacktrace I've run into.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 255, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/r351574nc3/projects/git/kfs-training/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    from common import tags
  File "/Users/r351574nc3/projects/git/kfs-training/common/tags.py", line 30, in <module>
    import html5lib
ImportError: No module named html5lib
```

Comment: Have you installed `html5lib`?

Comment: I do have html5lib installed, but I don't think course builder uses it since it asks that the html5lib-0.95.zip file be placed in the project lib folder. Also, I get this same error when I deploy to appspot.com.

Comment: You may need to manipulate your sys.path so the system can find the lib.  If you are deploying the lib but it can' t be imported then that will be your problem.

Comment: Modifying sys.path for something that should work out-of-the-box seems hacky to me. When I use `import html5lib` from the interpreter, it works fine. In cases like this, it's best to find how the application expects to find the library and accommodate it. I was able to figure that out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the answer out. The problem is that the html5lib-0.95.zip I was using had within it a directory called html5lib-0.95. I think coursebuilder required that all files be in the root path of the zip. Recreating the zip fixed this for me.